# How to make the Windows re-install process less time robbing?

Tags: partitioning, restore

Whenever I reinstall Windows (which happens often) I have to spend hours of configuration and installing drivers.

I thought of freezing the configurated system by creating a independent clone of it on partition B. In case of a re-install of Windows, it should format partition A and copy the image of partition B on it. The size of Partition "B" is 30 GB and "A" (the actual running system) the remaining disk space.

Now I'm asking myself if this is actually realizable **without** the use of additional 3rd party programs, and if so, how?

Alternative suggestions are welcome.

Comment: on Windows 8 you can update the image for the Refresh feature with a simple command.  Previous version of Windows doesn't have a built-in feature that can keep applications.  Previous version did have the ability to backup some personal settings and your personal files.  This is much easier with third-party software why would you throw out all those possible solutions?

Comment: You can create a backup as @Moses describes in his post **without** external software. To do that look up `imageX` which is on the windows 7 (and vista?) DVDs. Another option is windows build in backup tool. Boot from the DVD as if you were going to reinstall, then select the restore from backup option.

Comment: @Hennes I missed the part where he said he did not want external software. I made my answer community wiki if you want to modify it and add your comment in.

Comment: The OP did not mention the OS, but unless he or she is using ancient XP then the OS came with the software needed. No idea if win8 still has it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an image to install reinstall it from an external harddrive You can let the external harddrive stay connected to the computer as an "external partition". :-)

The image on the external harddrive has also the advantage, that you can restore other computers as well because you have the backup not just in a partition inside one computer.

**First you should create an image of the whole system:**

1. Open Backup and Restore by clicking at the Start button--> Control Panel-->System and Maintenance--> Backup and Restore.
2. In the left pane, click Create a system image, and then follow the steps in the wizard.

**Than you can create a system repair-cd:**

3. Type system repair disc into the search box in the Start menu.
4. The dialog box opens where you select the right drive and click Create disc. A CD will be fine as it only takes up 142MB of space.

**Than you can restore your pc/install it:**

5. Start you pc from the system-repair cd. You have to change your boot-order in bios
6. The system recovery option-screen will come up and now you can choose the right keyboard-input. Than click next.
7. System Recovery searches now for windows installations that you have on the hard drive.
8. Now choose the option "restore your computer using a system image you created earlier".
9. Click next.
10. Now the tool should find the image which you have saved on an external HD.
11. You should use "Use the latest available system image".
12. Click next
13. Click next again, because no other partitions are important now.
14. Click finish.
15. Accept the warning that shows up that you want to override you system.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is a roundabout way of asking "how can I keep a backup of a fresh install?"

I seem to recall a user here describing how he keeps backups of a fresh install, and it was pretty smart if you ask me. Install Windows, get everything installed, update, and repeat:

1. Install Windows, install drivers and install the most necessary programs that you need to be up and running (for me, I need Java, Flash, etc).
2. Shut down my computer and boot into an offline disk imaging tool. Personally, I use Macrium Reflect, but there are many out there.
3. Put the image anywhere you like. Put it on an external drive or an internal one (but obviously don't boot into it). Heck, you can put it on a network share.

If you need to restore from backup, cool. Restore from backup but **then** run the updates for your essential software that you installed, and then create another system image. The next time you need to restore, your programs are up to date.